# Capture console.log messages of an iframe after navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, logging

I want to capture the logging messages which are generated from an iframe immediately after the iframe is navigated. Currently I have something like this:

```
$(iframe).bind("load", null, function() {
    var logsToCapture = ["log", "info", "debug", "warn", "error"];
    logsToCapture.forEach(function captureLogs(logType) {
        var original = iframe.contentWindow.console[logType];

        iframe.contentWindow.console[logType] = function() {
            logUtil.log.apply(logUtil, arguments);
            original.apply(iframe.contentWindow.console, arguments);
        };
    });
});
```

This works fine, but it only captures messages *after* the initial page load. I'm specifically interested in getting the messages which occur during loading, since the page in question emits a lot of logs during its startup. I tried binding to "ready" rather than "load", since "ready" fires first, but then *no* events got captured.