# How to capture iframe console output with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, iframe

I'm trying to catch all types of console output from an iframe element. This is what I have, a slightly modernized version of [Capture console.log messages of an iframe after navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574385/capture-console-log-messages-of-an-iframe-after-navigation):

```
$.each(["log", "info", "debug", "warn", "error"], function (type) {
        var original = $("#result").contents().console[type];
        console.log("x");
        $("#result").contents().log[type] = function() {
            $("#console").append(arguments);
            original.apply($("#result").contents().console[type], arguments);
        };
});
```

#console is my div that should contain all the messages (for now), and #result is the iframe itself.

The problem is `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$("#result").contents().log')`